# Designing a 100 GBps network system with Raspberry Pi

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi, load-balancing

I want to check whether the following networking system architecture that is able to cope with 100 Gbps is feasible in terms of network design::

- Load Balancer that redirects the traffic to a rack of 100 rasperry pi devices (planning to use NGINX Load Balancer as a Software and a powerful custom desktop PC with latest hardware for the time-being).
- Three switches with 40 Ethernet ports/each put in between of the load balancer and the raspberries.

Would it impact the network throughput if the traffic goes through the network switches?. Any recommended hardware specifications for the load balancer?. Any alternatives to redirect the traffic from the load balancer to the rack?.

Answer (score 1):

The speeds that you expect are little unreal the Raspberry 3 B has a 100 Mbit Enthernet port and the Raspberry 3 B+ has 1 Gbit i think, also the switch will be a bottleneck. You could get a 10 Gbit switch but your pockets will empty. If you want 10 Gbit connection the budget way is buying a Network adapter with 10Gbit copper wire. To clear your knowledge watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGVPeB98zWI).